# What was the first successful mass tank battle of WW1?

Tags: weapons, world-war-one, tanks

What was the first big scale (over 50 tanks used) battle with the use of tanks in WW1?

Please note that the typical examples don't constitute good answer:

- Battle of Flers-Courcelette (Somme) was the first use of tanks but definitely not >50.
- Battle of Cambrai (November 1917) - which seems to be the standard answer on Google search - appears to be incorrect: as per Wiki, there were earlier battles with over 50 tanks fielded, though there were no good details/references.
- Second Battle of Villers-Bretonneux, France (1918) is notable for being first tank-vs-tank battle, but it was mere 3 against 3 quantity-wise.

Comment: Good question; I'd be interested in the answer to this. If I rightly recall, more than 60 tanks set out for the battle of Fleurs-Courcelette, but rather fewer than that arrived, tanks being what they were in those days. I look forward to seeing what we can find.

Comment: Good question? You do not ask for much. What is meant by "successfull"? The question is simply senseless!

Comment: The Germans didn't build many tanks during WWI so there are no examples of large tank v tank battles.  The Germans built around 20 of their A7V tanks and also used around 50 captured allied tanks, but there's no record of any battle involving more than 3 German tanks as mentioned above.

Comment: Since when is 50 a mass?

Comment: @Oldcat  - if you never had 50 tanks advance on you, it may not seem like "mass".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A likely candidate seems to be the [Battle of Messines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Messines_(1917)), which took place in June 1917. According to John F. C. Fuller in *[Tanks in the Great War, 1914-1918](http://books.google.com/books?id=fd9mAAAAMAAJ)*, 88 tanks were employed (p. 110).  He says 40 tanks advanced with the start of the attack at dawn, and an additional 22 set out with infantry in the afternoon.